# anchor links for each pageblocksections on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible for links for each  pageblocksections on top of the visualforce page just like hover links on standard salesforce.I know hover links are for related lists.As my visualforce has 16 pageblocksections it will become easy for user to navigate to each pageblocksection.Any ways to acheive this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just put an anchor just above your apex:pageBlockSection tags:

```
<a id="myAnchor"></a>
```

Then you'd have to build a simple nav. at the top of the page pointing to your anchors:

```
<a href="#myAnchor"></a>
```